# getting input in a function and calling it in another function

Tags: python, function, input

how would this work? Lets say I have a function called getInput that gets three numbers based on user input

```
def getInput():
    num1 = int(input("please enter a int"))
    num2 = int(input("please enter a int"))
    num3 = int(input("please enter a int"))
```

how would I use this function in another function to do checks regarding the input? For example

```
def calculation():
    getInput()
    if num1 > (num2 * num3):
        print('Correct')
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` the variables (`num1`, `num2`, `num3`) from the `getInput` function.

Like this:

```
def getInput():
   num1 = int(input("please enter a int"))
   num2 = int(input("please enter a int"))
   num3 = int(input("please enter a int"))
   return num1, num2, num3
```

then you can do:

```
def calculation():
    num1, num2, num3 = getInput()
    if num1 > (num2 * num3):
        print('Correct')
```

Comment: ahh thank you! Yea I did return the three variables in one iteration of my code, but in the calc function I only called the getInput function, i didnt know I had to use all three. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use an array for scalability. You may one day need to return 1000 values. Get the three numbers, place them in an array and return them as follows:

```
num_list = [];
i = 3;
temp = 0;
while i > 0:
     temp = int(input("please enter a int"));
     num_list.append(temp);
     temp=0;
     i--;
return num_list;
```

Now get the returned data and use it as follows:

```
 def calculation():
    getInput();
    if num_list[1] > (num_list[2] * num_list[3]):
        print('Correct')
```